# Installing CodeWeavers' crossover 20.0.4 fails on Linux

Tags: linux, python, emulation

I'm using Gentoo Linux and have Python 3.10 and 3.11 installed. I have a registered version of Crossover 20.0.4 that I'm trying to install using the `.bin` installer and I hit this error and installation fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py", line 12, in <module>
    from collections import MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'MutableMapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/bin/cxtie", line 135, in <module>
    import cxtiemain
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/cxtiemain.py", line 6, in <module>
    import c4parser
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/c4parser.py", line 10, in <module>
    import cxproduct
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/cxproduct.py", line 7, in <module>
    import cxconfig
  File "/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py", line 15, in <module>
    from UserDict import DictMixin as MutableMapping
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'UserDict'
```

I'm not the only one who seems to have had this issue:

There's this thread: https://www.codeweavers.com/support/forums/general/?ft=25;t=26;msg=267771

and this Ask Ubuntu question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1437185/cant-install-packages-after-trying-to-install-deb-file

How do I get it to install or do I have to upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace for the error originates from the file `/home/dev/Software/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py`. There are two attempts to import `MutableMapping` before it fails.

I edited my `/path/to/cxoffice/lib/python/cxconfig.py` and changed the import block from

```
try:
    # pylint: disable=E0611
    from collections import MutableMapping
    from collections import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from UserDict import DictMixin as MutableMapping
    from UserDict import DictMixin as Mapping
```

to

```
try:
    # pylint: disable=E0611
    from collections import MutableMapping
    from collections import Mapping
except ImportError:
    try:
        from UserDict import DictMixin as MutableMapping
        from UserDict import DictMixin as Mapping
    except ImportError:
        from collections.abc import MutableMapping
        from collections.abc import Mapping
```

I was able to successfully install, register and run a bottle from my codeweavers installation.

This may be particularly useful as CodeWeavers (in the forum link) mentioned they would not address the issue and the solution was only to upgrade. I may upgrade in the future, but I don't want this solution to be lost to those who need an older version to work.